# Multibutton display problem - data does not show

Tags: codenameone

We are using the OLD GUI builder and using MultiList to display data in our application. Our IDE is NetBeans.
For unknown reason it has just stop displaying data.
I know that codenameone suggests avoiding using Lists but we already use it in many forms.

This is the basic example of the code we use:

```
Map entry = new HashMap();

entry.put("Line1", "somedata");
entry.put("Line2", "somedata");
entry.put("Line3", "somedata");
entry.put("Line4", "somedata");

ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
data.add(entry);


cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(data));
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

When I click on a MultiList item, it navigates to another form as it should. The data is there but you can't see it.

We noticed that the same project worked fine on another pc where the old version of Netbeans codenameone plugin(3.x.x) was installed. When we upgraded the plugin to version 6, there was the same problem.

We tried building the app on the codenameone build server and installing the application on mobile phone but there is the same problem..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try invoking `Form.setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true)` and see if it works around the problem. Assuming that it does please update us in the issue to handle this [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2989).

Notice that disabling layout repaint results in a significant performance boost especially when scrolling.

Comment: We have set the  _f.setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true)_ in the "Before show" event but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you isolate this specific form from the UI so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Here is the link to simple application https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JEdRvuMfxCdU8YAeDSLDKRhWrxl05GMq that was built on PC1 with codenameone plugin 3.6.2. and Multilist works there. When moved to PC2 with plugin 6 MultiList doesn't work(doesn't show data). This may help:When "theme.res" opened on PC2 and saved and project moved back to PC1, then MultiList doesn't work on PC1 either.

Comment: When icon is added to Map then it works??  
`Resources res = fetchResourceFile();  `
`entry.put("icon", res.getImage("someimage.png").scaled(15, 15));`

Comment: We're pushing an update later today, please check if it resolved this issue